# REACT component not rendering into rails view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ruby-on-rails

The problem I have is when I render A list of items that includes a react component
then first page of the list is rendering the react component perfectly.
But when I scroll down the rest of the items are not rendering the react component.
So the react component is not being initialized with the infinite scroll.

**Infinite scrolling javascript file:**

```
import Rails from "@rails/ujs";
import Turbolinks from "turbolinks";
import * as ActiveStorage from "@rails/activestorage";
import "channels";

Rails.start();
Turbolinks.start();
ActiveStorage.start();

const images = require.context("../images", true);
const imagePath = (name) => images(name, true);

// Support component names relative to this directory:
var componentRequireContext = require.context("components", true);
var ReactRailsUJS = require("react_ujs");
ReactRailsUJS.useContext(componentRequireContext);

import "css/application";

// Companies - Inifinte scrolling
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function () {
  const postsDiv = document.getElementById("companies-list");
  const totalPages = parseInt(postsDiv.dataset.totalPages);

  let nextPage = parseInt(postsDiv.dataset.nextPage);
  let isFetching = false;
  let isFinish = false;

  function loadMoreCompanies() {
    if (isFinish || isFetching || !nextPage) return;

    isFetching = true;
    Rails.ajax({
      url: "/companies.js",
      type: "get",
      dataType: "script",
      data: `${location.search.slice(1)}&page=${nextPage}`,
      success: function (data) {
        isFetching = false;
        nextPage++;

        if (nextPage > totalPages) {
          isFinish = true;
          window.removeEventListener("scroll", scrollListener);
        } else {
          postsDiv.dataset.nextPage = nextPage;
        }
      },
    });
  }

  function scrollListener(event) {
    const customOffset = 0;
    if (
      window.innerHeight + window.scrollY + customOffset >=
      document.body.scrollHeight
    ) {
      loadMoreCompanies();
    }
  }

  window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollListener);
});
```

**Index Controller**

def index
load_filters
@items = Object.published
@items = apply_pagination(@companies)

@next_page = @items.next_page
@total_pages = @items.total_pages

respond_to do |format|
format.html
format.js
end
end

**Index.js.erb file:**

document.getElementById("companies-list").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<%= j render(partial: "companies/company", collection: @companies, as: "company")%>");

Comment: PROBLEM:
React component is not being initialized when rendering a partial from an index.js.erb file in a Ruby on Rails controller.